# Can not resolve hostname in Docker 1.10

Tags: docker, ip-address, hostname

I created a network and started 2 containers in the network

```
docker network create frontend
docker run -itd --name container1 --net frontend busybox
docker run -itd --name container2 --net frontend busybox
```

2 containers ping each other by ipaddress successfully but can not use hostname. In Docker 1.9, I can use both ipaddress and hostname but can not use hostname in Docker 1.10

```
docker exec container1 ping -c4 172.18.0.3 --> OK
docker exec container2 ping -c4 172.18.0.2 --> OK

docker exec container1 ping -c4 container2 --> FAILED
ping: bad address 'container2'

docker exec container2 ping -c4 container1 --> FAILED
ping: bad address 'container1'
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I have docker 1.10.0-rc4 and it works for me, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I mean, the 4 ping work fine

Comment: Hmm I dont know why but I think Docker 1.10 switch to embedded DNS server instead of /etc/hosts file

Comment: Works fine here using your sample code.

Comment: Could be a problem with firewalld as described here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20026

Comment: I disabled selinux but have no effect

Comment: Can you please add some more information? What is the host OS? What options are used to start the Docker daemon? What is the output of `docker info`?

Comment: Disabled selinux and firewalld if you use Fedora and CentOS 7, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Docker 1.10 Embedded DNS have trouble with selinux and firewalld on Fedora, RHEL and CentOS 7. You can work around by disabling selinux and firewalld.
Hope Docker team can fix this issue soon!

---

Update:
Docker 1.10.1 has fixed this problem! It works perfectly on Fedora 23, CentOS 7 and RHEL 7